# Windows 10 Home with BitLocker encryption - OK to allow updates

Tags: windows-10, encryption, updates, bitlocker, microsoft-surface

I recently began using the Bitlocker encryption that comes with my Windows 10 Home.

I would like to try to allow the Redstone/Creator's update + a list of security updates that I postponed, but I need to be sure that a system update with the disk encryption on will not cause system failure.

I am using a Surface 3 and there is no DVD drive, of course, so restoring or replacing the operating system if this goes badly could get complicated.

Comment: Best advice : DO NOT encrypt the system drive, and especially not with your hardware. Use instead [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) with a virtual drive for your sensitive data.

Comment: isn't veracrypt being discontinued soon?

Comment: No, it's built on the sources of TrueCrypt which is the one that is now abandonware.

Comment: also, could you elaborate about how to separate sensitive data, which i would consider everything in the user folder and the program data and app data folders . . . or is there more?

Comment: You are encrypting too much, and asking questions that already have answers on our forum.

Comment: ok, thanks. I think hyper-v might help make that work. And, you are probably right there  :P .   N00bz, right? *rolls eyes at self*

Comment: You should wait until RS3 is released to the stable channel.  You should also get yourself a flash drive in the event something does happen.  The simplest solution to avoid any problems with Bitlocker is to suspend it, install the updates, then resume it.